# Check if DAY_OF_WEEK is between Monday and Friday

Tags: java, android, error-handling, calendar, dayofweek

I'm trying to create a method which is checking if "today" is between Monday and Friday. For this I get with this  line `'int day = Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK;'`  the actual day. After that I fill a ArrayList with the days (Monday, Tuesday, Wendsday, Thursday and Friday). Now when I check if the actual day is in my ArrayList, i set `boolean DAY = true` else i set `boolean DAY = false`. I tryed the Method today and yesterday, but it allways sets the boolean to false.

What do I need to change that my code works? You'll find the code down here.

**Code**

```
                int day = Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK;
                ArrayList<Integer> daylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                daylist.add(Calendar.MONDAY);
                daylist.add(Calendar.TUESDAY);
                daylist.add(Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
                daylist.add(Calendar.THURSDAY);
                daylist.add(Calendar.FRIDAY);

                if (daylist.contains(day)){
                    DAY = true;
                }else{
                    DAY = false;
                }
```

Comment: Why can't you just check if day is between Calendar.MONDAY(value 2) and Calendar.FRIDAY(value 6) ?

Comment: the DAY_OF_WEEK, has to be one of those 5 day's

Comment: no, its because you have to Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Wow, that's like trying to kill a mosquito with a thermo-nuclear warhead :-)

Java [guarantees (in 1.5)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.AM) (unchanged up to [1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.ALL_STYLES) at least) that the values of `SUNDAY` through `SATURDAY` are contiguous (1 through 7) so it's a simple matter of checking a range.

However, `DAY_OF_WEEK` is *not* the day of the week, it's a field number (with the value 7) to be passed to the getter to *retrieve* the day of the week. The only time `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` itself will match an actual day will be on Saturdays.

You can use code such as:

```
Calendar myDate = Calendar.getInstance(); // set this up however you need it.
int dow = myDate.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
boolean isWeekday = ((dow >= Calendar.MONDAY) && (dow <= Calendar.FRIDAY));
```

Following this, `isWeekday` will be true if and only if the day from `myDate` was Monday through Friday inclusive.

Comment: why does it start at 1? It should start at 0. this makes it more awkward to do expressions like `while((today = ++today % 7) != startingPoint`

Comment: @likejiujitsu: I suspect it starts at one since no-one other than uber-nerds would use the phrase `"zeroth day of the week"`. Think of it from the _other_ side of the fence, all us poor C coders who have to continuously add one the `tm_mon` when outputting dates :-) It's easy enough in your case to do `while ((today = (today % 7) + 1) != startingPoint)` but, yes, you have to think about it a bit.

Comment: lol "that's like trying to kill a mosquito with a thermo-nuclear warhead", classic.

Comment: @paxdiablo the problem is most of the world would not call Sunday the 1st day of the week too. It's also crazy that Saturday and Sunday are both even (not even, odd). But I guess American Gods rest first and then do the work ;)

Comment: @Nux, I'm not sure how you could solve the "two consecutive evens" problem without moving to a six- or eight-day week. With seven days, two consecutive days *must* be the same parity. For the start of week issue, you can adjust the numeric values of the days if you're inclined. I actually like that idea, especially since ISO specifies Monday as the first day of the week. And rightly so, putting half of the week***end*** at the start of the next week seems a bizarre thing to do :-)

Comment: @Nux: We could always move to a fortnight-based "week", that would solve the parity problem and probably annoy US citizens, a worthy bonus :-) We'd just have to come up with seven new day names and either have both a weekbreak and weekend or expand our weekend to be four days at the end, working on Saturday and Sunday. Not sure how Abrahamic religious types would like that, given the creation stories they subscribe to.

Comment: @paxdiablo Europe uses 1 mon, ... 6 sat, 7 sun. Two consecutive days are normally even-odd within one week ;-)

Comment: Most of the world assumes starting week with work/school on Monday and resting on Sunday is good ;) https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:First_Day_of_Week_World_Map.svg

Answer (score 6):

`int day = Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK;` should instead be

```
Calendar cal; // The calendar object
....your other code for getting the date goes here....
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Your current code just gets the value of the constant `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`.

Comment: Correct! 
This is important if you want to get it work properly!

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick for you i assume.

```
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if (day >= Calendar.MONDAY && day <= Calendar.FRIDAY){
    DAY = true;
}else{
    DAY = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int day = Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK;
```

The logic is broken right here. DAY_OF_WEEK is a constant identifying which type of data we need to retrieve from a `Calendar` instance.

The simplest solution to your problem (since Calendar.FRIDAY > ... > Calendar.MONDAY) is

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if (day >= Calendar.MONDAY && day <= Calendar.FRIDAY)
  // do something
```

Answer (score 1):

First Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK is an integer field will always gives you 7. You need to create an instance of a Calendar like Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); By default it gives you the current date in current timezone.
Then you can call cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); which will give you any day between Sunday and Sat'day

Now you can check something like this

```
    if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY || cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
         System.out.println("Weekend");
     } else {
        System.out.println("Weekday");
     }
```

You can apply this logic to your problem!!